# Generate specific-length hash from a String using Java

Tags: java, string, hash

I want to hash a String (with variable length) into a fixed-length String (the length can be specified) using Java programming language. The output hash is for unique-detection only, there are no security-requirement here. All characters from the result String should be equal in randomness. Please give me a efficient way to do this (an algorithm, an existing Java method, a library,... are all okay). Thank you!

PS: I want to give some example for clarification:

```
    String message = "example message";
    // hash(msg, length) is the method I want
    // The output length can be specified in this method
    String hash1 = hash(message, 5); // "s40j7"
    String hash2 = hash(message, 8); // "orpx6klg"
```

Comment: must it result in a `String`? wouldn't `hashCode()` do it?

Comment: @user16320675 yeah but we want the length of the result String can be specified. The hashCode() only gives a fixed given length.

Comment: @codeđờ: almost all good hashing algorithms give a fixed length. You can just use *parts* of the output which *might* solve your whole problem, but it's unclear if your specified length is allowed to have some max value or if you need arbitrarily long fixed-sized output. Is it okay if the max length is limited (let's say to ~10 characters or something like that)?

Comment: yes, it kind of is fixed length (32 bits) - no limits were specified, we can easily transform a int to up to 8 hexadecimal numbers `String.format("%08x", string.hashCode())`  (or 10 decimal, or 32 binary digits)  (or maybe a trivial solution (`string.substring(0, length)`)

Comment: In any case, `hashCode()` is not good for checking uniqueness as it's not designed for it and there are many common collisions, which are much rarer in "proper" hashes like sha1.